# Infinite group not isomorphic to proper subgroup

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

We know that any finite group can't be isomorphic to any of its proper subgroups.

Some countably infinite groups, like $\mathbb{Z}$, do have this property of course, as $\mathbb{Z} \cong 2\mathbb{Z}$ . Could we do something like this for an $\mathbb{R}$? 
This raises some questions for me:

$1.$ Is there an obvious example of an infinite group that is not isomorphic to any of its proper subgroups?

$2.$ Is there an easy criterion to establish whether an infinite group does or does not have this property?

Comment: Why is $2\mathbb{R}$ a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Oh of course it's not, that's silly of me.

Comment: To answer the first question, an easy example is $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb Z/p_n\Bbb Z$. Any proper subgroup is necessarily missing an element of order $p_n$ for some $n$, where $p_n$ are primes

Comment: BTW, it's criterion (plural criteria), not criterium. Apparently a criterium is a short bike race!

Comment: Fundamental group of a closed oriented surface of negative Euler characteristic.

Comment: Shelah constructed an uncountable group which, like the finite groups, is not only not isomorphic, but does not even have the same cardinality as any of its proper subgroups.

Comment: Such a group is called Hopfian, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_group

Comment: @mt_ According to that link, wouldnt these groups be co-Hopfian?

Comment: @Krijn yes, co-Hopfian - my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An obvious example is the additive group $\mathbb Q$. You may be interested in this http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/269079615024.pdf

This article from *Mathematics Magazine* (vol. 72, no. 5, December 1999, p. 388) is "On Groups That Are Isomorphic to a Proper Subgroup" by Shaun Fallat, Chi-Kwong Li, David Lutzer, and David Stanford (College of William and Mary, Williamsburg VA 23187-8795).

Comment: Please give the complete citation in case the link dies.

Comment: Very nice paper in that link. You should do what lhf proposes.

Comment: @lhf: I just found this by googling OP's question. I added all the information I saw in the article, is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks.